# Do pillagers prefer any one specific type of biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As the question suggests...

I've been playing a lot of Minecraft recently and have noticed a lot of Pillager patrols in the immediate area surrounding my fortress. Often these patrols pass by my fortress with no (relatively) hassle, but the sheer amount of patrols in my area is quite alarming (On average, there is about 14 patrols a day in my area).

I haven't encountered any pillager outposts in my area as yet, so that rules that out. Which leaves this question, are pillagers attracted to a specific biome?

If it helps, my fortress is built in the centre of a small desert biome, and the structure itself is of fair size.

Comment: Exactly how many blocks wide is you fortress?

Comment: My fortress covers a 45 by 45 block area

Comment: Wow! That's big.

Comment: Thanks. It took a long time to build. Could the pillagers be attracted to the fortress itself?

Comment: Are you always in that area? Then of course they would spawn there, because it's the only area where they **can** spawn.

Comment: Initially I spent a lot of time there, but now I mainly explore, find villages, go mining and so on. Nearly all of these activities take place some distance away from the desert the fortress is built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Patrol#Java_Edition):

> Patrols spawn in any biome (except mushroom fields and its variants) at light level 8 or lower, only at night, like monsters.

Pillager Patrols do not prefer any specific biome. If you do not want Pillager Patrols to be around, you can build your fortress somewhere near a mushroom field.

Comment: Hi Max, please indicate it whenever you quote, and be sure to add the source.

Comment: Thanks I am just starter here :)

Comment: No problem :) !

Comment: I know it's kinda late, but I ain't moving my base to a mushroom biome. Too much of a hassle. Lokks like I'll need to get used to my new neighbours :P